# How can I adjust the height of ion-card?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm working on a QuizSelectionComponent using Ionic. I need to adjust the ion-card's height to fit all the content in the card, longer than the height of my laptop screen. I've tried adding `height: 100% !important;`, `height: auto !important;` and `height: 100vh !important;` in my CSS file; but none seem to increase the height of the card. Is there a setting I can override somewhere?

My QuizSelectionComponent template looks like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="quizData.length > 0">
  <ion-card style="height: 100vh">
    <ion-card-header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 logo">
          <div ion-card-avatar class="header-image"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
          <ion-card-title i18n>
            <h1>Quiz App</h1>
          </ion-card-title>
          <ion-card-subtitle i18n>
            <span>How well do you know Angular? Find out!</span>
          </ion-card-subtitle>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 info">
          <ion-icon name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-card-header>

    <section class="ion-card-content">
      <mat-toolbar>
        <mat-menu-button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
          <span i18n>Milestones &#x25BC;</span>
        </mat-menu-button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <div *ngFor="let quiz of quizData">
            <button mat-menu-item
                    [routerLink]="['/intro/', quiz.quizId]"
                    data-i18n="quiz.milestone">{{ quiz.milestone }}</button>
          </div>
        </mat-menu>
      </mat-toolbar>

      <mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="370px">
        <mat-grid-tile
          (click)="onClick()"
          *ngFor="let quiz of quizData"
          [routerLink]="['/intro/', quiz.quizId]"
          [ngClass]="{ 'completed': status === 'completed' }"
          [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url(' + quiz?.imageUrl + ') no-repeat center 10px',
                       'background-size': '300px 210px' }">

          <summary class="quiz-info">...</summary>
          <div class="status-icon">...</div>
        </mat-grid-tile>
      </mat-grid-list>
    </section>

    <ion-footer>
      <h3 class="text-center" i18n>&copy; 2020</h3>
    </ion-footer>
  </ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with: `height: 100vh;`

vh: Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Looks normal to me. Have you tried move `ion-footer` out of the card and/or change to pure ionic elements? Like `ion-segment` and `ion-grid` + `ion-list`. I noticed few times when I change an Angular element to correlative in Ionic the framework works as expected. I'm not saying that is your case, but might be worth a try.

Comment: I tried converting the mat-menu and mat-grid-list to Ionic but the ion-card height still doesn't adjust as expected.